# I want to pass the name of the song as an argument

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

After entering the song title in the message, I want to play the song title file using the arguments.

For example, if you type [test] in the message, the file test will be played. I want to declare a function to simplify it.

```
import discord
import subprocess
import asyncio
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio, PCMVolumeTransformer, AudioSource
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
        await connected.channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command()
async def play(self,musicname):
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    if voice.is_connected():
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(musicname+".mp3")
        voice_client.play(source)


bot.run("my_token")
```

Comment: .....and? What issues are you having? What doesn't work? What errors is it throwing? What are you expecting that isn't happening when running the code fragment you posted here?

Comment: You've exposed your discord bot token. You must change it now or it'll get exploited by other users.

Comment: Please do not expose your bot's token here, It's more like a password.

Comment: You want a function to simplify it? It seems pretty simple to me. What *exactly* do you want to simplify?